# Find sitecore items with a specific OMS profile?

Tags: sitecore

I have to find all items in Sitecore (or rather, in the contents) that have a certain OMS (marketing suite) profile checked in the "Tracking" attribute. The Tracking attribute appears to be stored as XML and has a raw value like

```xml
<tracking>
  <profile name="Widdly Scuds"><!-- some irrelevant keys... --></profile>
</tracking>
```

and I need to fetch, for example, all items with the "Widdly Scuds" profile.

The first solution I thought of was fast query over the Tracking attribute. Sitecore query or XML would have to crawl the entire contents each time, which would *probably* be unacceptably slow, but I'll try it if there are no alternatives.

This is the first fast query I tried:

```
fast://*[@Tracking = '%Widdly Scuds%']
```

but that returns 0 results. So I tried this:

```
fast://*[@Tracking = '<tra%']
```

and this (which would match the names of many of the profiles:

```
fast://*[@Tracking = '%A%']
```

And those also returns 0 results. I'm not really certain how Tracking is stored or queried, but it appears to be unusual since I can't get any results from it by any means.

The query needs to be fast enough to run a few dozen times during a short page rendering (probably not more than 20-30 seconds). The results can be cached for awhile, but not very long. The front page of a section of the site I'm working on needs to display an item count for each profile I'm querying, and there will be, maybe, 50-ish profiles.

So, how do I quickly get all items with a certain marketing profile?

**Edit:** I ended up using Lucene. Details of that adventure to appear in future questions, maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use query or iterate descendants, avoid starting the query from / if possible - start from the equivalent of /sitecore/content/someitem.

Another approach is to use a Lucene or other search index. [See the Sitecore reference for more info](http://sdn.sitecore.net/reference/sitecore%206/sitecore%20search%20and%20indexing.aspx).

Comment: Even if it's a Fast Query? For some reason, I was under the impression that using a path with fast query made the query slower that just using //*. Also, I'm already in the process of rebuilding it on Lucene, so you called it...

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, the Tracking field is actually stored as __Tracking. Whoops. So the query ends up being

```
 fast://*[@__Tracking = '%"Widdly Scuds"%']
```

This still has problems, as it's still trying to query XML via string operations and I may end up screwed later if a profile and key have the same name, but it works well enough for now.