# 'and' terms not reversible in Sitecore Fast Query?

Tags: sitecore

This one may be a bug, or it may be me failing to understand something.

Assuming there are some named 'Profile' items inside /sitecore/system/marketing center/profiles, this query returns all of them (tested in XPath Builder):

```
fast:/sitecore/system/marketing center/profiles/*[@Name='%' and @@templatename='Profile']
```

But if I reverse the two predicates, I get no results. That's this query:

```
fast:/sitecore/system/marketing center/profiles/*[@@templatename='Profile' and @Name='%']
```

Each of the predicates works separately, giving correct results to my eyes.

I wasted several hours on this today hunting this bug down in a Lucene indexer ([Man, I *hate* it when I'm right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884802/find-sitecore-items-with-a-specific-oms-profile)).

Any clues on why this only works one way around and how to avoid stumbling on it in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with Fast Query in 6.1/6.2. If there are more than 1 predicate and @@templatename goes first, it brakes the query.
I double checked - this should be addressed in 6.3.
I will talk to the documentation folks to get this included into the known issue list.
Sorry for the inconvenience.